# Install SSH key in UNIX server

Tags: windows, ssh, unix, sftp, private-key

I'm trying to connect to a UNIX server from a Windows server, through PSFTP.
I am using this command in CMD: `psftp.exe -i %userprofile%\.ssh\certificate.ppk username@unixserver`

The problem is that server is refusing the private key I have stored in the Windows server.
Is it possible to somehow install this private key in the UNIX server? I stored the same private key in my Unix home path (`/home/user/.ssh/certificate.ssh`) but the error is still there.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a public key from this private key, using putty-keygen or something similar. Put the public key on the server into the home directory of the user you want to connect as and add key to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

Then change the permissions appropriately:

```
cd ~
chmod 700 .ssh
chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: I uploaded the public key (certificate.pub) to `/home/user/` and added the key to authorized_keys, but the same error is showing: `Using username "slopez45".
Server refused our key
Using keyboard-interactive authentication.
Password:`. I am still using the same PSFTP command, as if try to connect using the public key, another error shows.

Comment: Did you create a user slopez45 on the server? If thats the username, the public key written to will be `/home/salopez/.ssh/authorized_keys` troubleshooting psftp will be helped by using the `-v` flag. http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.52/htmldoc/Chapter6.html#6.1.3